# Using an async constructor in Flutter

Tags: flutter, async-await, factory

I'd like to parse some stuff in a factory constructor, but one attribute will be given by a future. Unfortunately Flutter tells me that it isn't allowed to add a await/async to the factory constructor. Is there a nice way to fix this?

Thank you very much for your help!

This is my code:

```
class ClothDetails{

  final int clothId;
  final String title;
  final String image_path;
  bool pressed;

  ClothDetails(
      {this.clothId, this.title, this.image_path, this.pressed}
      );

  factory ClothDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> aJson) {

    return ClothDetails(
        clothId: int.parse(aJson['id']),
        title: aJson['title'],
        image_path: aJson['image_path'],
        pressed: isPressed(int.parse(aJson['id'])),
    );
  }

Future<bool> isPressed(int curId) async {
    bool help;
    final DatabaseHelper dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> a = await dbHelper.queryRowsById(curId);
        if(a.isEmpty){
          help =false;
        }else{
          help= true;
        }
    return help;
  }
}
```

Comment: Constructor({}){} have you tried this.

Answer (score 1):

you can`t do this

because the contractor only pass an instance of your class `ClothDetails`

you can't return a `Future<ClothDetails>` because it's not supported

but you can make a method in your class which is `Future`

I hope you got the idea